# Modify numbering style of subequations

Tags: numbering, amsmath, subequations

the following MWE produces a subequation numbering of 1a and 1b. However, I would like to have it displayed as 1A and 1B. I probably have to rename, \theequation, but so far I did not have any success :(. Do you know the correct code?

Thank you

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
3 &= 1+2 \\
6 &= 2+4 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can patch the `subequations` environment with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to use `\Alph` instead of `\alph`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\subequations{\alph}{\Alph}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed.}{}{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
3 &= 1+2 \\
6 &= 2+4 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If `hyperref` is already loaded, instead of patching `subequations` we have to patch `HyOrg@subequations`. The following does so (without testing whether `hyperref` is actually loaded):

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument
  {%
    \patchcmd\HyOrg@subequations
      {\alph}{\Alph}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}%
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
3 &= 1+2 \\
6 &= 2+4 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT2:** If you can control when `hyperref` is loaded, you can simply do the patching of the first code in this answer, and load `hyperref` afterwards. `hyperref` uses the definition in effect when it was loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunately I use patching of subequations together with the hyperref package. The patching only works if hyperref is loaded before amsmath and etoolbox. It then, however, generates a `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier...` warning.

If hyperref is loaded after amsmath and etoolbox, no warning is produced but then the patching also does not work. 

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Thet619 see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, now compiles correctly without any errors :)