# Simplified sectioning for article with hyperlinks

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, hyperlink

For my article I would like a very simple universal numbering with two counters, one for anything not equations (be they definitions, lemmas etc), and one for equations. The two counters share the same value most of the time, except when a non-equation item contains one or several equations (in which case the equation counter is reinitialized and the equation labels then contain both the item's index and the equation's index inside the list of equations in the item.

Also, I want the \theoremstyle{change} behavior with the modification that a period is to be inserted between the counter and the item name. In other words, I want a behavior summarized by this snapshot :

[image: Picture]

Here is my failed attempt :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage{color}

\theoremstyle{change}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{fact}[defn]{Fact}
\newtheorem{thrm}[defn]{Theorem}


\begin{document}

Hello world, I am a short article. I start with a definition : 
\begin{defn}\label{firstdef} Blah blah blah.
\end{defn}

This definition \ref{firstdef} just made is followed by a fact : 

\begin{fact} \label{firstfact} Bluh bluh bluh.
\end{fact}

The fact \ref{firstfact} above is followed by a standalone equation : 

\begin{equation} \label{abequation} a=b
\end{equation}

This equation \ref{abequation} is followed by a theorem containing two equations : 

Followed by a theorem containing two equations : 

\begin{thrm} \label{mainthrm}The following two equations hold : 
\begin{equation} \label{firsteqnintheorem} c=d \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{secondeqnintheorem} e=f \end{equation}
\end{thrm}

Notice the different labeling of the equations \ref{firsteqnintheorem} and \ref{secondeqnintheorem}
inside theorem \ref{mainthrm}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: For lists of equations, one typically uses subequations.(page 12 amsmath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there are better ways to achieve what you want, but the following works at least in the example you provided:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage{color}

\theoremstyle{change}
\newtheorem{defnHelper}[equation]{Definition} % These environments will only be used internally, never call \begin{defnHelper}...\end{defnHelper}!
\newtheorem{factHelper}[equation]{Fact}
\newtheorem{thrmHelper}[equation]{Theorem}
% This is the defn-environment you will call.
\newenvironment{defn}[1][]{ % Therefore, we define a new environment.
   \ifthenelse{ % (Only needed if you want to use the optional argument of your defn-environment.)
      \equal{}{#1} % If optional argument is empty (default), ...
   }{
      \begin{defnHelper} % ... just call defnHelper, ...
   }{
      \begin{defnHelper}[#1] % ... otherwise call defnHelper with optional argument.
   }
   \addtocounter{equation}{-1} % Make sure that the contained subequations have the same number as the containing environment.
   \begin{subequations}
}{
   \end{subequations}
   \end{defnHelper}
}
\newenvironment{fact}[1][]{ % The same for facts.
   \ifthenelse{
      \equal{}{#1}
   }{
      \begin{factHelper}
   }{
      \begin{factHelper}[#1]
   }
   \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
   \begin{subequations}
}{
   \end{subequations}
   \end{factHelper}
}
\newenvironment{thrm}[1][]{ % The same for theorems.
   \ifthenelse{
      \equal{}{#1}
   }{
      \begin{thrmHelper}
   }{
      \begin{thrmHelper}[#1]
   }
   \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
   \begin{subequations}
}{
   \end{subequations}
   \end{thrmHelper}
}

\makeatletter % As we use hyperref-package, we can adapt the subequations-numbering like that (thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520531/237192).
\AtBeginDocument
{%
   \patchcmd\HyOrg@subequations
   {\alph}{.\arabic}{}{\GenericError{}{Patching failed}{}{}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
   
   Hello world, I am a short article. I start with a definition: 
   \begin{defn}\label{firstdef} Blah blah blah.
   \end{defn}
   
   This definition~\ref{firstdef} just made is followed by a fact: 
   
   \begin{fact} \label{firstfact} Bluh bluh bluh.
   \end{fact}
   
   The fact~\ref{firstfact} above is followed by a standalone equation: 
   
   \begin{equation} \label{abequation} a=b
   \end{equation}
   
   This equation~\ref{abequation} is followed by a theorem containing two equations: 
   
   Followed by a theorem containing two equations: 
   
   \begin{thrm} \label{mainthrm}The following two equations hold: 
      \begin{equation} \label{firsteqnintheorem} c=d \end{equation}
      \begin{equation} \label{secondeqnintheorem} e=f \end{equation}
   \end{thrm}
   
   Notice the different labeling of the equations~\ref{firsteqnintheorem} and \ref{secondeqnintheorem}
   inside theorem~\ref{mainthrm}.
\end{document}
```

[image]
Some notes:

- Normally you shold use `see theorem~\ref{citedTheorem}` in order to avoid line breaks between the environment name and its number.
- If you want to have `see theorem (4)` instead of `see theorem 4`, use `\eqref{citedLabel}` instead of `\ref{citedLabel}`.
- <s>Until now I havent solved the problem of theorem heads (you want `4. Theorem.` instead of `4 Theorem`). I will add a solution using the `amstheorem`-package as I am more familiar with it.</s> See below.

---

**EDIT:** As I promised, here a solution for the theorem-header-problem. Replace `\usepackage{theorem}` by `\usepackage{amsthm}` and add the following code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{myStyle}%name
   {3pt}%                 Space above
   {3pt}%                 Space below
   {}%                    Body font
   {}%                    Indent amount
   {\bfseries}%           Theorem head font
   {.}%                   Punctuation after theorem head
   {.5em}%                Space after theorem head
   {\thmnumber{#2}.~\thmname{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{}{#3}}{}{~{\normalfont(\thmnote{#3})}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{myStyle}
```

You will have to play around a bit, especially with the space above and below. For testing reasons, I added an optional argument `[test]` to the fact-environment. If you want another style for that, just play around with the last argument of `\newtheoremstyle`.

```
\begin{fact}[test] \label{firstfact} Bluh bluh bluh.
```

[image]
Note that all lines (except the ones in which a definition, fact or theorems start) are indented as you have blank lines in your document. (I am pointing that out so that nobody thinks that the theorem numbers are put into the margin.)